# Project structure clarifications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am in about to create a project structure for my client. Its and MVC5 application interacting with web API

Following is my proposed structure. Do let me know if it looks right and adhere to naming conventions. Each of the items listed below will be a seperate project included in one solution.

```
CC.GRP.MCR.Common      -- Common utilities 
CC.GRP.MCR.Entities    -- Contain entities 
CC.GRP.MCR.Data.Layer   -- Contain entity framework , implementation of Generic repository and Unit of Work.
CC.GRP.MCR.Business.Layer    - Contains implementation Business methods 
CC.GRP.MCR.WebApi           - Contains the CRUD for web api
CC.GRP.MCR - The MVC project that contains Model View and controller
```

Comment: *Just a warning*: this question will likely be closed as the only answers you will get are opinion based. That said this structure is likely overkill for smaller sized projects. Also do merge Web APi and your MVC into a single project, this will prevent headaches later on with CORS requests as well as authentication with web api requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the ".Layer" from the project names,,

I would also put both the MVC and the WebApi in the same project, call it MCR.Web,,

Also, I think having Entities/Data/Business as 3 projects could be an overkill, it depends on the size of your project though.

Comment: The reason why I created a separate project for webapi is because we could replace it with any webservice if needed. May be WCF or anyother